# Como passar dados entre Activities

Tags: java, android

Tenho um código que transforma `getText` em `string` e gostaria de passar essa `string` pra uma outra *activity* de uma forma simples, mas não uma activity que vem logo após essa.

Meu código:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    buttonSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    cadastro_button  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cadastro_button);


    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    cadastro_button.setOnClickListener(this);


    buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

            attemptLogin(email, password);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Você deve usar o Intent pra isso, segue exemplo:

1ª Activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity.this, NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("key", value);
startActivity(i);
```

2ª Activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("key");
}
```

Comment: Simples e rapido ! Muito obrigada !

Comment: @SamaraCarvalho Se a resposta lhe ajudou você pode marcá-la como correta usando o **V** do lado esquerdo da mesma.

Comment: Leonardo, eu tentei alterar o título da pergunta, mas não estou certo de que seja isso mesmo (já que pouco entendo de Android). Você pode revisá-lo, por favor?

Comment: Alterei lá jbueno, obrigado.

Comment: Já dei o feedback de que a resposta foi util,porém não fica visivel em conta da minha reputação..